# Solving integral equation in matlab

Tags: matlab, integral-equations

I want solve the following equation using Matlab fsolve command but I am unable to write the code. The equation is as follows.

\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{1} \frac{e^{-xy}}{\log(x)}dx-y^2=0
\end{equation}

How I can write the code to solve it using Matlab. This is an example and may not have any solution.

Comment: You need to define x and y as symbols ( syms x y) then use int command ( check how it is used). Then if matlab can find solution of integral you get a function of y.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can solve this like the following:

```
syms 'x' 'y'
r = int(exp(-x*y)/log(x),'x',0,1)
solve(r - y^2, 'y')
```